# Dagger Component is not getting generated using kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

**ApiModule.kt**

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    private val BASE_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com"

    @Provides
    fun providesCountriesApi() : CountriesApi{

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CountriesApi::class.java)

    }

    @Provides
    fun provideCountriesService(): CountriesService {
        return CountriesService()
    }
}
```

**ApiComponent.kt**

```
@Component(modules = [ApiModule::class])
interface ApiComponent {
    fun inject(service: CountriesService)

    fun inject(viewModel: ListViewModel)
}
```

**CountriesService.kt**

```
class CountriesService {


    @Inject
    lateinit var api: CountriesApi

    init {
        DaggerApiComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    fun getCountries(): Single<List<Country>> {
        return api.getCountries()
    }
}
```

**CountriesApi.kt**

```
interface CountriesApi {
    @GET("DevTides/countries/master/countriesV2.json")
    fun getCountries(): Single<List<Country>>
}
```

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.demo.kotlinandroidmaster"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
        implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
        implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        implementation 'info.androidramp:loading-gear:1.0.4'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.21'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01"
        implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01"
        annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-rc01"
        annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-rc01"
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }
```

**Dagger component is not getting generated**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the annotation processor and the dagger compiler dependency.

In your `build.gradle` add after the other plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

and then, as dependency:

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.21'
```

Side note: you are not using the latest version of Dagger.

Comment: also I added `File>Other Settings>Default Settings>search"Annotation processor" `

Answer (score 1):

try doing a `build` of your project, before running the app.

Dagger components are generated when a `Build` is done and removed when a `Clean` is done.

**Edit**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AppModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        InjectionBinder::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, InjectionBinder::class]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: YourApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: YourApplication)
}
```

here's a working example of an AppComponent

Comment: Tried it, Not getting generated ..... this used to work using java ... not happing using kotlin

Comment: how does your `ApiComponent` look ?

Comment: That is the class dagger generates right ? ..... its not getting generated is the bug

Comment: I edited my comment, how does the ApiComponent(not the generated one) look

Comment: I am using this sample `https://github.com/DevTides/CountriesAndroid`
I am not able to make it into work .... can you review

Comment: will do :) going to let you know in a minute or two

Comment: @Devrath try changing your `ApiComponent` to look like mine and let me know if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196737/discussion-between-a-local-nobody-and-devrath).